# Hibernate EntityManagerImpl: Getting or setting up access to it

Tags: hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee, jpa

We are developing a Java EE application using Hibernate as a JPA provider. We now wish to use Hibernate Criterias but for that I need to get access to the HibernateEntityManagerImpl.

We have this currently in our componentContext.xml

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.volvo.it.lsm"/>

<!-- JPA EntityManagerFactory -->
<bean id="EmployeeDomainEntityManagerFactory" parent="hibernateEntityManagerFactory"      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"> 
     <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="EmployeeDomainPU" /> 
</bean>
```

and in our classes:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "EmployeeDomainPU")
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
session.createCriteria(...);
```

Note that JPA2 has a (different) Criteria API as well. It's harder to use IMHO, but it's more type-safe, and has the same advantages as the Hibernate Criteria API (be able to dynamically compose a query)

Answer (score 2):

```
EntityManager em ...

//if you want Session with JPA 1.0
org.hibernate.Session session = (org.hibernate.Session) em.getDelegate();

//If you use JPA 2.0 this is preferred way
org.hibernate.Session session2 = em.unwrap(org.hibernate.Session.class);

//if you really want Hibernates implementation of EntityManager, just cast
//it (this is not needed for Criteria queries though). Actual implementing class
//is of course Hibernates business and it can vary
org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl emi = 
 (org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl) em;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call [em.getDelegate()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getDelegate%28%29) and cast it to the Hibernate class